# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libSDL2.so" not found

Tags: android-ndk, sdl-2, dlopen

When I am loading my application through android studio, I am getting following error:

I have compiled `SDL2` library separately using `Android.mk/Application.mk` and added those so paths in my application.

```
buildToolsVersion = '23.0.2'

minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 17
targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
```

Error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: com.example.hellojni, PID: 14607
>                                                                         java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libSDL2.so" not found
>                                                                             at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
>                                                                             at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
>                                                                             at com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.(HelloJni.java:66)
>                                                                             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1095)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3083)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: Is libSDL2.so included in your APK? It sounds like it's not being packaged.

Comment: Is there any way to check all other libraries are included in my apk?

Comment: APKs are just zip files. You can open them with any zip tool and see what was included.